# GraphQL "not equal" operator?

Tags: graphql

I have a GraphQl API for listing a bunch of items, and I can query it perfectly etc.
But now I'd like to query for a subset of that list where one property can have 'all possible values except one specific one'.

For example, I want to query something like this:

```
{
  items(status: !"Unwanted"){
    id
  }
}
```

That exclamation mark obviously doesn't work, but it illustrates what I am after.
Can't find any information about this online.

Does anybody know of a way to do this?
I would really hate having to enumerate all possible wanted values instead of just excluding the one unwanted value. This would be really bad design and is not scalable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can define the schema (implement the server) then you can add a second argument like `statusExcept` to the `items` field. Then in the resolve method check if status or statusExcept was set and deliver the items according to that.

It the server API is fixed there is afaik nothing that you can do except getting everything and filter on the client.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I can see how that would work easily. Does GraphQL really have no concept of "not"? Seems like such a glaring omission.

Comment: @batijo GraphQL has no concept of search, rather you have to implement the search using tools given to you by GraphQL, for example arguments. GraphQL is just a language specification, it remains neutral about how search should work in your particular API or application.

Comment: But it does! It's a query language. It has query parameters that allow you to search for specific values (however they may be implemented by the schema in the background). So if I can look for e.g. { status: "New"}, which is status="New", why does it not have a concept of status != "New", for example: { $not: { status: "New"} }?  Seems like an obvious thing to add.

Comment: I did end up adding a kind of "notNew" query parameter, which the resolve() function translates into a more complex query, as suggested by @Matthias247 above.

Comment: @batjko It's not really like that :) When you do `status: "New"`you just pass an argument to the GraphQL resolve function. It can be for a search, but it can also be for other purposes. Eg pagination, choosing the needed size of the image. For those arguments $not doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Good point. I didn't really see it as "passing arguments to the resolve function" before but it makes a lot of sense. I usually just understood it as "query parameters" and all that the term implies.  Fair enough. Thanks for the explanation, @freiksenet!

Comment: I think graphql to put "query" in their acronym but no advanced search capabilities is really disappointing, I hope it gets the power of a mongo query ($not, $lt,  etc...) our of the box with no serverside changes to make it work

Answer (score 22):

Use `ne` :

```
{
  items(filter: {status: {ne: "Unwanted"}}){
    id
  }
}
```

Comment: missing `filter: {}` around `status: {ne: "Unwanted"}`. This should read `items(filter: { status: {ne: "Unwanted"} })`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How would this work on the resolver side?

Answer (score -2):

Using GraphQL version `4.3.2` the syntax has changed and you will need to use `notIn`

```
{
  items(filter: {status: {notIn: "Unwanted"}}){
    id
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not GraphQL. That "filter" parameter must be custom-defined as part of the schema and have your custom resolver that can take and apply that filter object. See this rejected proposal on the GraphQL spec: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/271#issuecomment-426167175